# Objective-c Don't pause while entering in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, background

is it possible not to pause the application while in background mode (when you press the home button and the app minimizes)? I have some timers and variables that i don't want to get paused.

EDIT:

I have followed this example http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-keeping-the-ui-responsive-and-a-background-thread-pattern/

I have called a timer inside however it's not getting called when i enter background mode:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    if(self.viewController.timerquest != NULL)
    {
        if(self.viewController.timerquest.timerRunning){
            // Save varibales
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performLongTaskInBackground) withObject:nil];
        }
    }
}



- (void) performLongTaskInBackground
{
    // Set up a pool for the background task.
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // perform some long task here, say fetching some data over the web.
    //...
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // Always update the components back on the main UI thread.
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(completeLongRunningTask) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool release];
}

-(void) updateTimer{

    // Update my timer. This method is not being called in background mode
}
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: In that example, the "background" he refers to is simply a background thread that runs concurrently to the main UI thread. It allows you to do complex computations without freezing your UI. It does *not*, however, allow your program to keep working as long as it wants when your app is in the background. You are allowed only a very limited amount of time to run after the user leaves you.

Comment: I believe [this][1] is what you're trying to do. You need to dispatch the task you want to do asynchronously, and provide a handler to gracefully stop the task when iOS pauses your app.

[1]http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 2):

use **Long Running Background tasks** according to manual:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: You mean Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background instead? I don't see anything usefull in Long Running Background tasks, it all about GPS locations and audio which i really don't care about.

Comment: @Marc yes, Finite-Length if it fits more your case

Comment: I don't know if I understood it correct, but if I have some timers in my controller which I need to not pause while in background mode I have to protect those by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler or what? Has anyone some experience with this? By the way, the example there isn't very clear.

Comment: see some example: http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-keeping-the-ui-responsive-and-a-background-thread-pattern/

Comment: Hmm this examples shows how to perfom something in the background like downloading, I just want to continue to run something in the background (a timer in a class in the viewcontroller).

Comment: you have to start it in background and keep it running there, or create new timer when going from/to background

Comment: Could you please search and investigate and learn yourself? We've given you path, this is not code (fitting your case) factory

Comment: I am investigating, it's just so confusing. The example you just gave me, where does it go? controller? appdelegate?

Comment: appdelegate, its written in developer guide i posted as first

Answer (score 1):

Have a read here at the [Apple non-technical documentation](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/multitasking.html) or at the [technical reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Answer (score 1):

Could you replace the timer with delayed background notifications?

Comment: The timer is for runnning a countdown only.

Comment: @Marc a countdown to what? If it's something the user should know about when it finishes, it sounds like a perfect candidate for local notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what happens when your timers fire, you want to [set up a local notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13) that fires at the same time the timer would have; this is useful when the timer would present something for the user to act on. As far as saving variables, you'll want to use -applicationDidEnterBackground: to save whatever state you need to, so that the correct variables can be loaded/generated when the app relaunches (which may not happen until the app has been exited and completely restarted again).

The types of tasks that are allowed to perform long running background tasks are pretty limited, specifically for things like GPS and playing audio. Everything else needs to decide on a task-by-task basis whether to simulate continued running (such as turning a timer to a local notification), pausing and saving necessary state to continue the next time the app is run, simply cancelling the task and gracefully restarting/notifying the user upon resuming the app, or asking for a finite length of time to finish a task (for things like finishing a download).

Comment: The edit to your post does not cover apps entering the background. Your best bet is to decide whether to turn your timer into a notification for your user, or to pause it and resume it when the user returns--you can even simulate what would have happened at each timer pulse as part of resuming.